# Magento custom block shows Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in Home Page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created custom module for banner package is Destiny and module is Banner.

In config.xml code is as following:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <banner>
            <class>Destiny_Banner_Block</class>
        </banner>
     </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <destiny_banner>
                <file>destiny_banner.xml</file>
            </destiny_banner>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Block is as following:

```
class Destiny_Banner_Block_Banner_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
}
```

In phtml file of home i am displaying block as

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('banner/banner_list')->setTemplate('destiny_banner/banner/list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

When i use createBlock('core/template') it's working.

Layout file code is

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <banner_banner_index translate="label" module="banner">
    <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">  
            <block type="banner/banner_list" name="banner_list" template="destiny_banner/banner/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </banner_banner_index>
</layout>
```

Config file as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Destiny_Banner>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Destiny_Banner>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <destiny_banner_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Destiny_Banner</module>
                    <class>Destiny_Banner_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </destiny_banner_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <banner>
                <class>Destiny_Banner_Block</class>
            </banner>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <banner>
                <class>Destiny_Banner_Helper</class>
            </banner>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <banner>
                <class>Destiny_Banner_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>banner_resource</resourceModel>
            </banner>
            <banner_resource>
                <class>Destiny_Banner_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <banner>
                        <table>banner_banner</table>
                    </banner>
                    <banner_store>
                        <table>banner_banner_store</table>
                    </banner_store>
                </entities>
            </banner_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <destiny_banner>
                    <file>destiny_banner.xml</file>
                </destiny_banner>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Destiny_Banner>
                    <files>
                        <default>Destiny_Banner.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Destiny_Banner>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Destiny_Banner before="Mage_Adminhtml">Destiny_Banner_Adminhtml</Destiny_Banner>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <banner>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Destiny_Banner</module>
                    <frontName>banner</frontName>
                </args>
            </banner>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <destiny_banner>
                    <file>destiny_banner.xml</file>
                </destiny_banner>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Destiny_Banner>
                    <files>
                        <default>Destiny_Banner.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Destiny_Banner>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <banner>
            <banner>
                <breadcrumbs>1</breadcrumbs>
            </banner>
        </banner>
    </default>
</config>
```

Block file list.php as

```
class Destiny_Banner_Block_Banner_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    /**
     * initialize
     * @access public
     * @return void
     * @author Ultimate Module Creator
     */
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $banners = Mage::getResourceModel('banner/banner_collection')
                        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
                ->addFilter('status', 1)
        ;
        $banners->setOrder('title', 'asc');
        $this->setBanners($banners);
    }
    /**
     * prepare the layout
     * @access protected
     * @return Destiny_Banner_Block_Banner_List
     * @author Ultimate Module Creator
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'banner.banner.html.pager')
            ->setCollection($this->getBanners());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getBanners()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * get the pager html
     * @access public
     * @return string
     * @author Ultimate Module Creator
     */
    public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you get your page content with URL `banner/banner/index`?

Comment: No m getting not found

Comment: Can you confirm if your module is enabled from `System > configuration > Advanced`?

Comment: Yes it's enabled

Comment: Have you also create a controller in this module 
named as Banner.php?

If not, then please create one CMS page and write below code on that CMS and check if this block is calling in CMS or not

{{block type="banner/banner_list" name="banner_list" template="destiny_banner/banner/list.phtml" }}

Comment: Yes as BannerController.php

Comment: No it's also not displaying output on test page

Comment: Are there any errors? Please check log or enable developer mode because there does not seem any errors in code which will prevent block output.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out this issue. It was occurring because of other module was conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

May be your block is not having a permission. Please verify from below path

**System > Permission > Blocks** and check your block name is in list or not.

If not please try to add and then check:

1. Click on Add new Block
2. Block Details:
    a. Block Name: banner/banner_list
    b. Is Allowed : yes

Comment: There only Users and Roles not Blocks in menu.

Comment: Can you share your module files?

Comment: Which file? There are many files.

Comment: Config and Block file.

Comment: I have added file code in question.

Comment: Can you try to comment the Block functions and try, I tried on my Local its working fine.

Comment: Do you mean comment functions of Block file? Which function?

Comment: Yes, like this.

class Destiny_Banner_Block_Banner_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    
}


and in my config :

In my config:

'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Destiny_Banner>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Destiny_Banner>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <banner>
                <class>Destiny_Banner_Block</class>
            </banner>
        </blocks>        
    </global>        
</config>'

Comment: And in CMS I just call :

 {{block type="banner/banner_list" name="banner_list" template="destiny_banner/banner/list.phtml" }}